# Как правильно (!) переслать большой текст

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc

Проект на платформе asp.net mvc
Передо мной стоит задача послать View, которое строит схему из XML. Чтобы не делать второго запроса (сначала послал View, а затем запрашиваю схему с сервера), мне необходимо встроить XML во View. Причём XML достаточно большой.
Вопрос - как это сделать правильно? Какие Best practice есть на этот случай? Конечно, можно сделать невидимый div с этим XML внутри, либо текстовое поле с этим XML, но не покидает ощущение, что можно лучше и красивее.

Comment: В теге script самое то. Калбэк функция и в скобках этот xml

Comment: XML формируется динамически на сервере. Встраивать содержимое тега script посредством Razor?

Comment: не спец в asp.net) прилепить в конец вьюхи можно просто прибавлением 3 строк, можно шаблонизатором. Скрипт отработается после загрузки вьюхи. В доме висеть не будет в отличие от скрытого дива. Сразу передаешь его в функцию на обработку.